# Save database entrys from array in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, typeorm

I scrape data from a website and save them to an array. I would like to save this array threw a mysql database.

I am using nodejs as backend framework, mysql database and typeorm as database framework.

This is the code from my express webserver where I want to pass the elements via for-loop threw the database:

```
app.get('/dev', async (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body)
const channelData = await scrape.scrapeChannel()
console.log(channelData.namearray.length);

for (i = 0; i < channelData.namearray.length; i++) {
 const creators = await database.insertCreator(channelData.namearray[i], channelData.datearray[i], channelData.imgarray[i])
    res.send(creators)
}});
```

This is my code for the database connection:

```
async function insertCreator(training, date, img) {

const connection = await getConnection();

// create
const creator = new Creator();
creator.img = img;
creator.training = training;
creator.date = date;

// save
const creatorRepo = connection.getRepository(Creator);
const res = await creatorRepo.save(creator);
console.log('saved', res);

// return new list
const allCreators = await creatorRepo.find();
connection.close();
return allCreators;}
```

**If I run the code I get the following error message:**

AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError: Cannot create a new connection named "default", because connection with such name already exist and it now has an active connection session.

It seems like I don't close my database connection. But I don't get where and why.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening and closing connection for each inserts. You are getting this error because new connection attempt made before old connection get closed.

Try to open connection once, pass the connection to insert function, perform all inserts and finally close connection.

```
//Pseudo code here
connection = getConnection()
for loop {
  insertCreator(connection, params) 
}
connection.close()
```

If this is part of production code, I would recommend to use connectionPool for each requests, so that all request will be served correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response.
Now I'm getting this error:

TypeError: connection.getRepository is not a function

I think it is because I don't pass the argument correctly. What I don't mentioned. The code with the for loop is in another file than the code with the insertCreator function.

Do you have any guess?

Comment: Is this new error? Are you able to insert any items?

`getConnection()` should be same as your old implementation and `typeorm` library should give you connection object to access `getRepository()` function.

Can you update your question with latest code change and problems you are facing?

I would like see the details of `getConnection()` function (mask all connection options like host, username and pwd)

Comment: To avoid this kind of errors , please use connectionPool .

Comment: Okay I will try it with using connection pool.